# How to add a shadow to the icon of a MaterialButton in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, shadow

I have a MaterialButton in my Android application that includes an icon. I want to add a shadow effect to the icon, similar to the material design guidelines. However, I'm unsure of the best approach to achieve this.

Here is the relevant XML code for my MaterialButton:

`<Button     app:icon="@drawable/ic_premium"     app:iconGravity="textStart"/>`

I have attached two images to illustrate my current result and the desired result:

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foAIG.png)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yn8Z.png)

Could someone please guide me on how to add a shadow effect to the icon of a MaterialButton? Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MaterialButton noshadow

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton

use CardView, card_view:cardElevation
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview?hl=zh-cn

Comment: I need a shadow for the icon, not the button

Comment: CardView is ViewGroup!!!!

Comment: <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        ...>

  <ImageView
   .../>
     
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>